# CodeIgniter redirect() error

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

When I test my CodeIgniter redirect code, the following error occurs:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/allci/CIone/application/config/autoload.php:1)
Filename: helpers/url_helper.php
Line Number: 544
```

What is causing this?

Comment: Could you provde the relevant part of that code?

Comment: You are probably echo-ing out something before the redirect. Can we see your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output started at (as the error says) `/var/www/allci/CIone/application/config/autoload.php on line 1`. This means that either autoload.php is a mixed HTML/PHP file (which it probably shouldn't be) or, more likely, autoload.php is has leading white space before it's opening `<?php` tag.

The `<` should be *the first* byte in the file - you need to make sure there are no spaces, tabs, carriage returns etc at the start of the file. You also need to make sure the file does not have a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of it.